# keyword/compiler option in C to promise not to overlap different pointers

Tags: c

Is there a keyword/compiler option in modern standards of C language which tells the compiler that I promise not to overlap different pointer-variables in memory?
Say,

```
void f(int *x, int *y);
```

promise that my manipulations with `x` will not implicitly affect `y`. E.g. `x` and `y` are arrays and I know their sizes, and I will not screw up the limits, etc.

I suppose that would allow for a better optimization by the compiler.

Comment: This is usually called aliasing btw

Comment: If I hand you two pointers, how would the compiler know they're are pointers to arrays, much less their dimensions?

Comment: @Blrfl It wouldn't. That's why we need to promise to the compiler that they don't overlap and that we won't go out of range. (As for being pointers to arrays: They don't need to be, as the differences - if any - don't matter.)

Comment: @delnan:  The OP appears to be asking about whether there's some way to promise the compiler that array limits won't be blown through.  Not happening in C as it stands.

Comment: “`x` and `y` are arrays and I know their sizes, and I will not screw up the limits, etc.” Good news: the compiler is already assuming that you are not screwing up the limits. See http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/07/31/From-Pascal-strings-to-Python-tuples http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/20/Attack-by-Compiler  http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/03/13/indeterminate-undefined or most of the other undefined-behavior related posts.

Comment: @Blrfl Why would that be impossible? It'd be a *promise*, what happens if it's broken it would be the user's problem, not the compiler's. What's more: Since out-of-bounds accesses are undefined behavior, it is allowed for compilers to assume that (without any "promise"), and virtually every optimizing compiler does that anyway. The non-overlapping part is what needs to be promised to achieve further optimizations, which would be hindered by the potential for aliasing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  Check out the `restrict` keyword.

[Restrict details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict)